# Firebase Realtime Database Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

Recently I have been working on a project using Firebase Realtime Database. Till now everything was going very well, but suddenly the code broke from the part of my code which I wrote during the start of the project.

[Here is the snippet from my code. I am using this algorithm to update the code in the database.]

```
export const addUserToProject = async (project_id, user) => {
await firebase.database().ref('projects/' + project_id).once('value', snapshot => {
    const numUsers = snapshot.child('numUsers').val()
    if (!snapshot.child('users').exists()) {
        snapshot.ref.child('users').set([user])
        snapshot.ref.child('numUsers').set(numUsers + 1)
    }
    if (snapshot.child('users').exists()) {
        const users = snapshot.child('users').val();
        snapshot.ref.child('users').set([user, ...users]) // This line
        snapshot.ref.child('numUsers').set(numUsers + 1)
    }
}, error => {
    throw new Error(error.message)
})}
```

When the function is called, it make non-stop recursive calls at the highlighted lines and after a few seconds, it shows the following error:

```
index.esm.js:649 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at syncTreeRemoveEventRegistration (index.esm.js:9897)
at repoRemoveEventCallbackForQuery (index.esm.js:11464)
at onceCallback (index.esm.js:13242)
at CallbackContext.onValue (index.esm.js:12274)
at index.esm.js:13118
at exceptionGuard (index.esm.js:638)
at eventListRaise (index.esm.js:11082)
at eventQueueRaiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate (index.esm.js:11057)
at eventQueueRaiseEventsForChangedPath (index.esm.js:11044)
at repoSetWithPriority (index.esm.js:11346)
at set (index.esm.js:12990)
at Reference.set (index.esm.js:14745)
at addProjectToUser.js:15
at valueCallback (index.esm.js:14526)
at onceCallback (index.esm.js:13241)
at CallbackContext.onValue (index.esm.js:12274)
at index.esm.js:13118
at exceptionGuard (index.esm.js:638)
at eventListRaise (index.esm.js:11082)
at eventQueueRaiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate (index.esm.js:11057)
at eventQueueRaiseEventsForChangedPath (index.esm.js:11044)
at repoSetWithPriority (index.esm.js:11346)
at set (index.esm.js:12990)
at Reference.set (index.esm.js:14745)
at addProjectToUser.js:15
at valueCallback (index.esm.js:14526)
at onceCallback (index.esm.js:13241)
at CallbackContext.onValue (index.esm.js:12274)
at index.esm.js:13118
at exceptionGuard (index.esm.js:638)
at eventListRaise (index.esm.js:11082)
at eventQueueRaiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate (index.esm.js:11057)
at eventQueueRaiseEventsForChangedPath (index.esm.js:11044)
at repoSetWithPriority (index.esm.js:11346)
at set (index.esm.js:12990)
at Reference.set (index.esm.js:14745)
at addProjectToUser.js:14
at valueCallback (index.esm.js:14526)
at onceCallback (index.esm.js:13241)
at CallbackContext.onValue (index.esm.js:12274)
at index.esm.js:13118
at exceptionGuard (index.esm.js:638)
at eventListRaise (index.esm.js:11082)
at eventQueueRaiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate (index.esm.js:11057)
at eventQueueRaiseEventsForChangedPath (index.esm.js:11044)
at repoSetWithPriority (index.esm.js:11346)
at set (index.esm.js:12990)
at Reference.set (index.esm.js:14745)
at addProjectToUser.js:14
at valueCallback (index.esm.js:14526)
```

Any help would be very grateful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You forgot to include your code.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry for that. Just did.

Comment: I can't see why there's any recursion (where is this "highlighted" code you speak of) ...

Comment: @JaromandaX Thats why I am confused as well. The code was working till a few days ago. But it is now breaking. Also, I have tried going back in my git history to check whether my previous codes are working or not. But they are not working as well.

Comment: so, the issue may well be something else that has changed

Comment: @JaromandaX you mean to say something changed in firebase? But I don't think company like Google could just change something like that that soon without any change in their documentations as I can't see any changes in the documentation. Also, I have tried previous versions of firebase as well to check whether there are any changes to the package or not.

Comment: Not the cause of the problem, but the entire code can be replaced with the much simpler: `let updates = {}; updates["users/"+ user] = users; updates["numUsers"] = firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1); firebase.database().ref('projects/' + project_id).update(updates);`

Comment: `you mean to say something changed in firebase` - no, something changed - your code, some library - programs don't just work one day then stop for no reason the next

Comment: @JaromandaX , For that, I already tried going back to the previous versions of my code to check for the changes in the libraries. Also, the error is coming up on the basic firebase command. Moreover, if there was a library change, then other fields of the database must have got updated as well, but there is a recursive call on the same line only.

Comment: all I'm saying is, if it works, then one day stops working, something has changed - only you can possibly track down what has changed between it working and it not working